# Java: for loop using i

Tags: java, for-loop

I have this:

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
    lbl1.setText(""+tarningar[i]);
```

Now I would like to change lbl1 to lbl+i.. so it prints out on lbl0,lbl1,lbl2,lbl3,lbl4.

How can I do this?

Comment: the lbl1.setText, i would like to change that to lbl[i].setText so it doesnt set to lbl1, but lbl0,lbl1,lbl2,etc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add all of the labels to an array, then you can write:

```
lblarray[i].setText(""+tarningar[i]);
```

Comment: better yet, have only that array. There generally *shouldn't be* variables with index numbers in the name.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
Label lbl0;
Label lbl1;
Label lbl2;
Label lbl3;
Label lbl4;
/* ... */
for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
  lbl1.setText(""+tarningar[i]);
```

do this:

```
Label labels = new Label[5];
/* ... */
for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
  labels[i].setText(""+tarningar[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Store the labels in array and then:

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
    labelArray[i].setText(""+tarningar[i]);
```